# Preventing functions to call each other

Tags: r, scope, environment-variables, environment

I have these two R scripts which will be sourced in same R instance.

Script 1:

```
fun1 <- function(x, y)
{
  ret = x+y+mean(x,y)
  return(ret)
}

fun2 <- function(x, y, z)
{
  k = fun1(x, y)
  print(x+y+k)
}
```

I want script 2 to be like this

```
fun3 <- function(k, l)
{
  k = fun4(k, l)
  m = k / sd(k,l)
  return(m)
}

fun4 <- function(k, l)
{
  ret = k+l+mean(k,l)
  return(ret)
}
```

But what people write is

```
fun3 <- function(k, l)
{
  k = fun1(k, l)
  m = k / sd(k,l)
  return(m)
}
```

But I dont want to allow functions in script 1 to be called from script 2. How can I do this?

I know I can do this in script 1 but there are many functions like fun2 and some of them are huge, so this is not possible for me

```
fun2 <- function(x, y, z)
{
  fun1 <- function(x, y)
  {
  ret = x+y+mean(x,y)
  return(ret)
  }
k = fun1(x, y)
print(x+y+k)
}
```

I know about creating new environments, but I am not sure will that help.

Comment: Can I ask why? `fun3` explicitly calls `fun1` from script 1. Do you want to call a different `fun1` that is not the one from script 1?

Comment: Where do functions for `script 2` come from, then? Perhaps you could do some smart `source`ing?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thats I want to avoid, I don't want to allow anyone to call  function not in their script. I want that script 2 to have its own function fun4 doing same thing as fun1.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik : These two scripts are going to be written by two different persons.

Comment: I don't understand. `fun3` seems to call `fun1`, which -- unless you re-define it elsewhere -- is defined in script 1. So either give the function called from within `fun3` a different name, or introduce a sensible conditions within `fun3`. I'm afraid I can't say much more without a minex.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your use case? Why do you think sourcing the functions in separate environments won't help? See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13092757/6455166, in the *Alternative using sys.source* section.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I'm guessing what OP is after is that person writing script2 gets a warning "fun1 does not exist" if the person has not created themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `?environment`s for this. See also [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890522/set-a-functions-environment-to-that-of-the-calling-environment-parent-frame-fr?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

```
env1 <- new.env()
env2 <- new.env()

assign("myfun", value = function(x) {
  mean(x)
}, envir = env1)

assign("myfun", value = function(x) {
  mean(x^2)
}, envir = env2)

myx <- 1:10

with(env1, myfun(myx)) # 5.5
with(env2, myfun(myx)) # 38.5
```

Basically, every single skript is gonna be run in its own environment.
Is this what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of each script just delete the functions defined in them.